# Camera rotation getting reset when i use orbit controls three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I am using three js to view 360 images, i have created sphere and overlay an 360 image texture on the sphere, i set camera rotation to the image center, but every time I rotate image, orbit controller resetting the camera rotation to (0,0,0)
code is attached, please help me out thanks in advance.

```
const texture = loader.load(img.url, (texture) => {
  texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  sphere.material.map = texture;
  sphere.material.needsUpdate = true; // Ensure material updates

  sphere.material.map.dispose();
  
  controls.object.rotation.set(-2.3553, 1.57, 2.3553)
  //tried to camera.rotation as well
  setLoading(false)
});
```